# Compatibility with Exporter 5.57

Tags: perl, import, backwards-compatibility

Should I prefer one of these 4 versions when I use `Exporter` in a module which should work with Exporter 5.57 (the one that came with Perl 5.8.3)?

```
# 1
use Exporter; 
our @ISA = qw(Exporter); 
our @EXPORT_OK = qw(some_func);

# 2
use Exporter;
our *import = \&Exporter::import;
our @EXPORT_OK = qw(some_func); 

# 3
use base 'Exporter';
our @EXPORT_OK = qw(some_func);

# 4
use parent 'Exporter';
our @EXPORT_OK = qw(some_func);
```

Comment: And what happened when you tried?

Comment: #3 is the *right way*. Why do you suspect that you should do anything different?

Comment: The latest Exporter should work fine with Perl 5.8.3, so it sounds like you actually want compatibility with Exporter 5.57. Updated question.

Comment: Note that parent.pm didn't come with Perl 5.8.3

Comment: @Borodin: Because I found the second version I thought maybe there is a reason not to inherit from Exporter.
And I thought `parent` is newer than `base` and therefore maybe better but now I know in Perl 5.8.3 `parent` is not yet available.

Comment: Re "I thought maybe there is a reason not to inherit from Exporter", Indeed there is: It's a bad design. See my answer for the mechanism that replaces it.

Comment: @choroba: I did not try it yet but I think I would have seen no difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I'd tend to use:

```
use Exporter ();
our @ISA       = qw(Exporter);
our @EXPORT_OK = qw(...);
```

Which will work with every version of Perl and Exporter released this century.

Other ways might be more compact but the above is not exactly onerous to type. And it only needs to be done once per module. The other ways come at the expense of compatibility with older versions of Perl, so I stick with the above.

Comment: So you're saying he should use the broken design to be compatible with 5.6.0 when he only asked to be compatible with 5.8.3? That's poor advice.

Comment: No, I'm saying I've seen no practical reason for not using the above. There's nothing inherently broken about inheriting from an Exporter base class. (Though there are broken things in Exporter.pm's particular implementation.)

Comment: What do you mean? The very design of using inheritance to import is broken. That's the very definition of "inherently broken".

Comment: `import` is by definition a class method call rather than a function call. So even caring whether somebody's module inherits it or implements it themselves is a violation of the encapsulation principle.

Comment: No, caring if your module violates another's encapsulation isn't a violation of encapsulation. The first actual violation is Windows/Animal/Message/... being an Exporter even through windows/animals/messages/... aren't Exporters. The second is using `our @ISA` as an import mechanims.

Comment: Also `use Exporter qw(import); use namespace::autoclean;` breaks. Certain MooseX::Types modules were broken by this trap in the past. (They actually use Sub::Exporter, but the same principle applies.)

Comment: The same principle does indeed apply: `@ISA = 'Sub::Exporter';` makes no sense. For the same reason that Exporter moved away from it, Sub::Exporter doesn't even allow it. I thought you were arguing `@ISA = 'Exporter';` was good, but it looks like we're on the same page now???

Comment: No, I'm saying that `use Exporter 'import'` and `use Sub::Exporter -setup => {...}` **both** break if you use namespace::autoclean-like modules. Because the `import` function in your module has been imported, namespace::autoclean will clean it out of your symbol table. Inheriting the `import` method doesn't suffer from that. Inheritance is also a good thing because it means you can potentially override parts of the exporter's behaviour. (However, as I said Exporter.pm's implementation is not great, and there are very few methods you can usefully override.)

Comment: Wrong about that too. You don't need to inheritance to provide a wrapped version of a function. // To get around the problem with autoclean, you can use `sub import { goto &Exporter::import }`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66787/discussion-between-tobyink-and-ikegami).

Answer (score 1):

Perl 5.8.3 came with Exporter 5.57, and it supported the following even back then:

```
use Exporter qw( import );
```

That's better than inheriting from Exporter, and it's better than manually importing `import`.

Comment: If you want to advocate keeping old versions of core libraries then I think you don't need my advice. You won't have seen it, but a huge amount of work has gone into every version of Perl, including its core library modules, to keep it back-compatible with earlier versions. You said it correctly with *"The latest Exporter should work fine with Perl 5.8.3"*. There is no reason to explicitly import `Exporter::import` when the modern idiom is available.

Comment: @Borodin, I didn't advocate keeping old version of core libraries, and I did advocate using the modern idiom (`use Exporter qw( import );`). Inheriting from Exporter makes no sense (since you're not making a subclass of Exporter), so Exporter was restructured to provide `import` using the standard mechanism (importing) rather than subclassing. Subclassing is still supported for backwards compatibility, but it stopped being necessary at least as far back as Perl 5.8.3.

Comment: It will stick with 5.8.3 as to smallest supported Perl version.